# How to connect sql database with wordpress

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I wrote a sql database code and wanted to connect it with a wordpress to create a web page. I searched for how to do it but i did not find the answer. How can i connect the sql code with wordoress? If it can’t be do you any recommendations for something else than wordpress accept sql database?

I used oracle sql developer

Answer (score 0):

WordPress/ClassicPress system [requirements](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/):

> - PHP version 7.3 or greater.
> - **MySQL** version 5.6 or greater **OR MariaDB** version 10.1 or greater.
> - HTTPS support.

WP/CP uses it's own database structure and strongly discourages running direct SQL queries from the code. There is a special global variable `$wpdb` (an instance of a [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb)) which should be used to perform any database request.

If you want to use WP, you should probably convert your SQL database to match WP native structure (if it's possible) and then use `$wpdb` to manage your tables/rows/fields.

Otherwise if you really need a custom database structure, you might want to build a custom solution with some common PHP frameworks like **Laravel** ([Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database)) or **Yii2** ([Working with Databases](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-databases)).